# Partial Update Failed via Viewset Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to update a field in my model whenever an object link is called through the api. I'm using Django Rest Framework to handle the creation of api.

The link to a single object is

```
example.com/api/pk/ where pk is the object id.
```

In the model viewset, I wrote a partial update method to handle the addition of 1 to the field whenever the object is called upon.

```
class RocNationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=RocNation.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-pub_date')
    serializer_class=RocNationSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)


    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        serializer=RocNationSerializer(rocnation, roc_views=F('roc_views')+1, partial=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The method is not carrying out the operation. The field in the model is not updated. What am I missing?

Comment: do you use `patch` method?

Comment: No. How will I go about that?

Comment: replace `PUT` to the `PATCH` in your request

Comment: But 'partial=True' has been added already. And according to my understanding, it also means I'm trying to patch the model.

Comment: `partial_update` called on `patch` request, you can try rename method to `update`

Comment: done that.. not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154656/discussion-between-bear-brown-and-yoyo).

Comment: Could you please explain why you want this?? Your view seems not to be executing, if it had it would raise a `rocnation not defined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
@detail_route(methods=['POST','GET'])
def assign(self, request, pk):
    rocnation = self.get_object()
    data = {'roc_views': rocnation.roc_views + 1}
    serializer = RocNationSerializer(rocnation, data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

So visit example.com/api/1/assign

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do in order to update partial fields with Django API Rest :

In your django module :

```
#create API folder
mkdir api
```

Then add `__init__.py file` :

```
#create __init__.py__ file
touch __init__.py
```

Now you have to create `serializers.py` file :

```
from rest_framework import serializers 

from .models import "your model"
from .views *

class YourModelUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = "your model"
        fields = [
            #list of fields which could be updated
        ]
```

Create a `view.py` file inside API directory :

```
from rest_framework.generics import (
    CreateAPIView,
    UpdateAPIView,
    DestroyAPIView,
    ListAPIView, 
    RetrieveAPIView,
    )

from .models import "your model"

from .serializers import (
    YourModelUpdateSerializer,
    )

class YourModelUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView) :
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourModelUpdateSerializer
```

Finally, add `urls.py` file :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import (
    YourModelUpdateAPIView, 
    )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', YourModelUpdateAPIView.as_view() , name="Update"),
    ]
```

It should work because it works in my project ;)

You have Django API REST doc [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview)

Comment: I aready have serializers in my app folder. Must I create a new folder to achieve this?

Comment: You have to create an API folder inside your module. Then, inside you can add `__init__.py`, `serializers.py`, `views.py` and `urls.py` files ;) All these files according to Django API Rest Framework